# problem with right triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Ok, so here is my problem, I have a right triangle ABC, the length AC and BC are known. We also know the angle BCE.

From there I want to be able to calculate the distance ED which is the altitude of the triangle BCE.
Is it possible, or do I have not enough known parameters?

Comment: Geometrical inspection says that you have enough parameters. Now to find out how to use them.

Comment: $\angle BCE =\theta$ is known. Now clearly, $ED = CE\sin(\theta)$ Can you use trigonometry to obtain $CE$?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I wasn't sure about this. I can't seem to be able to solve this, I've been trying for some time already.
After some research, I got something like ED = BC*tan(BCE)/(1-tan(BCE)²)

But it's giving me approximate result and becomes completely wrong when the angle becomes too big.

Comment: Are you familiar with cosine rule? Specifically, does step 3 "Now for the triangle BEC - angles BCE and EBC are known - calculate angle BEC" of markisab's answer, can you do that? If not, then google up cosine rule.

Comment: Yes I can, thank you for everything, that helped me a lot, I was thinking too complicated when the solution is actually quite simple

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do.

1) look at the big triangle $ABC$. You know two distances and know that it is a right triangle, so you can get the angles, using formulas for cosinus and sinus in a right triangle.

2) look at the triangle $ACE$. You know all angles and you know the length $AC$ so with the formula $a/\sin(\alpha)=b/\sin(\beta)=c/\sin(\gamma)$ you get all lengths.

3) look at the triangle $CDE$. You know all angles and one length, so you can find all lengths with the formula above. This gives you $ED$.

Answer (score 0):

1. AC and BC are known - calculate AB using Pythagorean theorem
2. All lengths known - right angle triangle - you can calculate other angles of triangle ABC
3. Now for the triangle BEC - angles BCE and EBC are known - calculate angle BEC
4. Now you know all angles and length BC, use sine theorem to calculate other lengths...
5. Now you know BE and angle EBD - use sine function to calculate length ED,

and that should be it, if can't you trigonometry then try with similarity of triangles... you have enough parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Sine rule would be of great help here.

Firstly,

by Pythagoras rule we can find length of $AB$.

Now by sine rule we can find $\angle BAC$ and $\angle ABC$ using $\frac{BC}{\sin A} = \frac{AB}{\sin C}$ or $\frac{AC}{\sin B} = \frac{AB}{\sin C}$

Now find $\angle AEC$ which is straight forward

Then "$\frac{AC}{\sin(\angle AEC)} = \frac{EC}{\sin A}$" gives $EC$

Then $\sin(\angle BCE) = \frac{ED}{EC}$